# drawing a tube with 2 sample paths within the tube

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'd like to be able to draw his diagram in tikz if anyone has pointers on where to begin? Specifically how would you draw the curves?

[image]

is there anyway to scale the image using \begin{axis}[width=24cm,height=8cm] as i'd like to stretch a image a bit (3x wide as high)

Comment: You could just include the image. If you want to try and draw this using [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) you are more likely to get hep if you post some code that shows you have at least tried....

Comment: There is a nice Matlab function called matlab2tikz that does exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is rather straightforward to produce something along these lines.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,samples=101]
\draw[stealth-stealth] (0,3)node[left]{X} |- (7,-3) node[below]{$\lambda$};
\draw[thick] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:6] ({\x},{cos(\x*30)+1}) node[right]{B};
\draw[thick] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:6] ({\x},{cos(\x*30)-1}) node[right]{C};
%
\draw plot[variable=\x,domain=0:6] ({\x},{cos(\x*30)}) node[right]{A};
%
\draw[red] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:6,] ({\x},{cos(\x*30)+0.8*cos(\x*120)});
%
\draw[gray] plot[variable=\x,domain=0:6,] ({\x},{cos(\x*30)+0.9*cos(\x*360-45)});
%
\draw[thin,gray] (1,2.8) -- (1,-3) node[below]{D};
\draw[thin,gray] (4.5,2.8) -- (4.5,-3) node[below]{E};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: is there anyway to scale the image using \begin{axis}[width=24cm,height=8cm] as i'd like to stretch a image a bit (3x wide as high)

Comment: @user175199 Sure, just use `\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily,samples=101,xscale=3]`.